# Black line on texture after baking

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

I have an issue with black lines on the texture after baking the model. I have researched on the internet but have not found out how to solve the problem.

[image]
[image: I have no idea what is it]

Comment: Maybe overlapping UVs? Do you bake onto a new object? What does it give if you unwrap again this copy (with the Smart UV Project option)?

Comment: If I make a copy with unwrap and make new UV Map (throug smart), all of my materials lost their places. Im new at this. Is it possible to move materials to copy of this model and recalculate UV?

Comment: I meant duplicate object A, unwrap object B with Smart UV Project then bake again from object A to B. If it doesn't work maybe share a part of your object so that we can try? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: .blend is about 500mb. How to reduce it? Cut part of model?

Comment: Yes only keep a part ;)

Comment: You can also use another platform like workupload for example but anyway keep it small